# CSV file - browser opens it instead of downloading

Tags: php, csv

I wrote PHP code to export data to `.csv` file. The exported `.csv` file was downloadable on my own PC. But in client's server, the `.csv` file was not downloadable, it was in readable format (the browser can read and print the file contents like a `.html` file).

I used `header()` before accessing the `.csv` file.

Is it a server side problem or do I need to change my code?

Comment: How could we tell you if you should change your code if you don't show it to us? Please share your code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to send headers to tell the client what kind of file to expect and what to do with it.

```
header ('Content-Type: text/csv');
header ('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="put_your_preferred_file_name_here.csv"');
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the header sent by the server to let know to the browser that it need to download it instead of show it.

Add this to make the file being open by excel

```
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel")
```

or this for a more standard type

```
header("Content-type: text/csv")
```

Comment: Which browser causes you the issue? As GordonM suggested it the Content-Disposition: attachment could also help

Comment: All major browsers(FF3+, IE7+, Safari)

Comment: @JulienDucro Ducro I set the header but still unable to download my csv on safari.

Answer (score 1):

I very much liked [this solution](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/htaccess/force-files-to-download-not-open-in-browser/). In case the URL isn't reachable (any more):

Put a `.htaccess` file into the same folder and add this line to it

```
AddType application/octet-stream .csv
```

that's all. (The original Link has some more file extensions, but this is the one for the OP).