# File download for csv works in local host but not when live

Tags: php, csv, http-headers, download

I am creating a csv file from nested array and it works fine with a download link to the csv file in the localhost, but on live host it won't download. This is what is in my php file:

The headers declared:

```
/**
* Declare headers for CSV
 */
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=registration.csv");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
```

The Function that outputs the csv file:

```
/**
* Function will output the scsv file
* @param the csv $data in nested array form array(array("","",""),array("",""...)...)
*/
function outputCSV($data) {
$outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
function __outputCSV(&$vals, $key, $filehandler) {
    fputcsv($filehandler, $vals); // add parameters if you want
}
array_walk($data, "__outputCSV", $outstream);
fclose($outstream);
}
```

The link that I used in local:

```
<a href=".../csv/csv.php">Download CSV</a>
```

Won't work on Live site. Instead of downloading it just takes me to the csv.php page and outputs the array in a string like this.

...ID,"Coach One","Coach Two",Work,Cell,Email,...

Comment: What if you change `header("Content-type: text/csv");` for `header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");` ?

Comment: Try taking out the pragma and expires headers.  And put the filename in double quotes, with single quotes around the string, like is illustrated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6544382/csv-file-browser-opens-it-instead-of-downloading

Comment: I just tried what you posted above, and it still just ouputs it onto the screen.

Comment: sounds like its a server config issue, or a filepath issue.  HArd to tell without you expanding on 'Won\'t work on Live site.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try hardcoding the csv into the code.  Replace these lines with the ones you have to see if your data being passed has bad characters.  Maybe specifying the charset will help.

```
header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=data.csv');
$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($output, array('Column 1', 'Column 2', 'Column 3'));
```

As described here:

http://code.stephenmorley.org/php/creating-downloadable-csv-files/

Comment: it worked when replaced what have with yours. it must be reading  it with bad characters. there are qoutes around the data when it just comes to printing it. the data looks like this...

ID,"Coach One","Coach Two",Work,Cell,Email,"School/Squad Name",

it that the problem the qoutes?

Comment: If mine works, and yours does not, then what you've done is incorrect.  Use this code as the base, and slowly add pieces to it so it does what you want, test it on every addition of code.  When it stops working, the last thing you did was wrong.

Comment: Please post the corrected code in an answer and you will receive upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not setup to really debug your code.  You can try this though if you like.  I know it works.

```
$out = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');
while (($row = $res->fetch(Zend_Db::FETCH_NUM)) != false) {
    fputcsv($out, $row, ',', '"');
}                       
rewind($out);
$csv  = stream_get_contents($out);
header("Content-Type: application/csv;");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"foo.csv\"");        
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");        
echo $csv;
exit(0);
```

Adjust the loop as needed to iterate on your results.